# Show each response result using chronos-report-maven-plugin (Jmeter - Chronos)

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

I'm working with performance testing (REST), using jmeter and maven.
In my pom, I have the following plugins:

- chronos-jmeter-maven-plugin: to execute my jmx project
- chronos-report-maven-plugin: to create the report site with the performance metrics

Sometimes, there are some tests failures and I'm not able to see what was the response of the service. Is there any way to see all the requests and responses in the report? Or the failed responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration section should allow you to enable responses and additional details. Try true and true. Could you include your config section of the plugin in your pom file?

```
                            <configuration>
                                <description>This is the description of the generated report</description>
                                <title>Report title</title>
                                <showaverage>false</showaverage>
                                <showpercentile>false</showpercentile>
                                <showinfotable>false</showinfotable>
                                <showtimeinfo>false</showtimeinfo>
                                <showsummary>true</showsummary>
                                <showdetails>false</showdetails>
                                <showresponse>true</showresponse>
                                <showhistogram>true</showhistogram>
                                <showthroughput>false</showthroughput>
                                <showgc>false</showgc>
                            </configuration>
```